# silverlight's design in MVC shows only on Visual Studio and not Blend

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, blend

I've added a new silverlight application to my MVC solution.
I've entered some code into the MainPage.xaml and App.xaml, and it seems fine in VS.

However, when I want to see and edit it in Blend I can't.  I see only the code.  there
are no References (which are seen in VS), no Assets, no States, no Parts.

Does anyone know how to solve it? maybe there is a different approach ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Blend are you using (full, express for WP7 etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  Downloaded Expression Blend 5 Preview for Silverlight5, 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9503 ,
Works side by side with Blend4.
Seems Blend4 doesn't know to handle Silverlight 5.